# Out Of Memory while loading images

Tags: android, image, memory, android-listview, scrollview

I tried android scrollview and listview for loading images.

Both giving "out of memory" exception after loading 30-40 images.

How can i free memory ?

Searched already a lot but didn't find anything, can you please help ?

Comment: Are those static images from drawable folder???

Comment: what are the size of the images .i.e (width X Height) ? if big then u can resize them ,u can also enbale max heap siz = true

Answer (score 0):

you can check here 
**[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)**

in that tutorial , you can directly implement your project (lazylist)